# Jquery Fade transition doesn't look right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple fade transition that hides the current div, while un-hiding the div below it. However the transition doesn't look right as when the fade is happening it briefly shows all the div's. I'm new to using jQuery so could anyone show me how i could polish this up a bit to make it look better when the fade transition takes place?

p.s i know the jQuery could be coded better, but again I'm pretty new to jQuery so if anyone has a better way of coding this let me know.

Thanks.

HTML:

```
<div id="home" class="content" align="center"style="width:400px;height:350px;background-color:grey;">
    <h2>Home</h2>
    <p>DIV 1 CONTENT GOES HERE</p>
     <button id="buttonone" type="button">Click Me!</button> 
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
<!-- /Home -->

<!-- Portfolio -->
<div id="portfolio" class="panel" style="width:400px;height:350px; background-color:grey;">
    <div class="content">
        <h2>Portfolio</h2>
        <p> DIV 2 CONTENT GOES HERE </p>
        <button id="buttontwo" type="button">Click Me!</button>
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /Portfolio -->

<!-- About -->
<div id="about" class="panel" style="width:400px;height:350px;background-color:grey;">
    <div class="content">
        <h2>About</h2>
        <p>DIV 3 CONTENT GOES HERE</p>
        <button id="buttonthree" type="button">Click Me!</button>
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /About -->

<!-- Contact -->
<div id="contact" class="panel" style="width:400px;height:350px;background-color:grey;">
    <div class="content">
        <h2>Contact</h2>
        <p> DIV 4 CONTENT GOES HERE </p>
        <button id="buttonfour" type="button">Click Me!</button>
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /Contact -->
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#buttonone").click(function(){
$("#home").fadeOut();
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#buttontwo").click(function(){
$("#portfolio").fadeOut();
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#buttonthree").click(function(){
$("#aboutfour").fadeOut();
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#buttonthree").click(function(){
$("#about").fadeOut();
});
});


$(function() {
    $('#portfolio').addClass('hidden').hide();
    $('#buttonone').click(function() {
        if ($('#portfolio').hasClass('hidden')) {
            $('#portfolio').removeClass('hidden').fadeIn(1000);
        }

        });
});

$(function() {
    $('#about').addClass('hidden').hide();
    $('#buttontwo').click(function() {
        if ($('#about').hasClass('hidden')) {
            $('#about').removeClass('hidden').fadeIn(1000);
        }

        });
});

$(function() {
    $('#contact').addClass('hidden').hide();
    $('#buttonthree').click(function() {
        if ($('#contact').hasClass('hidden')) {
            $('#contact').removeClass('hidden').fadeIn(1000);
        }

        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you add each button `class="button"` attribute, and run the following jQuery:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass("hidden"))
        {
            //if already hidden, do you want to display it back?
            $(this).removeClass("hidden");
        }
        else{
            $(this).parent().parent().next().fadeIn(1000);
            $(this).addClass("hidden");
            $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut(1000);//this will hide the button as well, is this okay?
        }
    }
});
```

So, when a button is clicked the div containing that button will be hidden, and the next div will be showed, is that right? Then, at the beginning, only the first one will be displayed? I am not clear about the functionality.

**UPDATE**

I got it working finally. There you go: https://jsfiddle.net/ev64mqsp/

note that I included one extra div for Home div to make all main content divs have the same structure.

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    if($(this).next().hasClass("hidenext"))
    {            
        $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut(1000)
        $(this).parent().parent().next().removeClass("hidenext");
    }
    else{
        $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut(1000);
        $(this).parent().parent().next().addClass("hidenext");
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="home" class="content" align="center"style="width:400px;height:350px;background-color:grey;">
   <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
      <p>DIV 1 CONTENT GOES HERE</p>
      <button class="button" id="buttonone" type="button">Click Me!</button> 
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /Home -->

<!-- Portfolio -->
<div id="portfolio" class="panel" style="width:400px;height:350px; background-color:grey;">
    <div class="content">
       <h2>Portfolio</h2>
       <p> DIV 2 CONTENT GOES HERE </p>
       <button class="button" id="buttontwo" type="button">Click Me!    
       </button>

    </div>
</div>

<!-- /Portfolio -->

<!-- About -->
<div id="about" class="panel" style="width:400px;height:350px;background- color:grey;">
    <div class="content">
       <h2>About</h2>
       <p>DIV 3 CONTENT GOES HERE</p>
       <button class="button" id="buttonthree" type="button">Click Me!</button>     
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /About -->

<!-- Contact -->
<div id="contact" class="panel" style="width:400px;height:350px;background-color:grey;">
    <div class="content">
       <h2>Contact</h2>
       <p> DIV 4 CONTENT GOES HERE </p>
       <button class="button" id="buttonfour" type="button">Click Me!</button>
<!-- ... -->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /Contact -->
```

Comment: hi erkaner yes that is what i want to happen, and i tried using your code however it doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: did you remove all the previous code when trying? I guess you would not need them. I updated the code with new order, can you try again? Also, can you use debugger to see which line has problem?

Comment: yeah i removed all the previous code and just used yours, but when the button is clicked nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Class hidden (supposed to have `display:none`) should be added when `fadeOut()` finish for a good animation. If you want to mantain div position you may use `visibility:hidden` removing `display:none` given by `fadeOut()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("body > div").not("#home").addClass("hidden");
    $("button[type=button]").click(function(){
        if ($(this).parent().attr('id') == 'home') { 
            $(this).parent().fadeOut(1000,function(){
                $(this).addClass('hidden');
                $(this).next().fadeIn(1000,function(){$(this).removeClass('hidden')});
            });
        } else {
            $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut(1000,function(){
                $(this).addClass('hidden');
                if ($(this).next().hasClass('panel')) {
                  $(this).next().fadeIn(1000,function(){$(this).removeClass('hidden')});
                }
            });
        }
        
    });
});
```

```css
.hidden { display: none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home" class="content" align="center"style="width:400px;height:200px;background-color:grey;">
    <h2>Home</h2>
    <p>DIV 1 CONTENT GOES HERE</p>
     <button id="buttonone" type="button">Click Me!</button> 
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
<!-- /Home -->

<!-- Portfolio -->
<div id="portfolio" class="panel" style="width:400px;height:200px; background-color:grey;">
    <div class="content">
        <h2>Portfolio</h2>
        <p> DIV 2 CONTENT GOES HERE </p>
        <button id="buttontwo" type="button">Click Me!</button>
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /Portfolio -->

<!-- About -->
<div id="about" class="panel" style="width:400px;height:200px;background-color:grey;">
    <div class="content">
        <h2>About</h2>
        <p>DIV 3 CONTENT GOES HERE</p>
        <button id="buttonthree" type="button">Click Me!</button>
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /About -->

<!-- Contact -->
<div id="contact" class="panel" style="width:400px;height:200px;background-color:grey;">
    <div class="content">
        <h2>Contact</h2>
        <p> DIV 4 CONTENT GOES HERE </p>
        <button id="buttonfour" type="button">Click Me!</button>
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /Contact -->
```

Comment: i want only one div to be visible at a time, and when they click the button the next div should appear in the same position as the old fading div